# Apparently the Blue Mountains trains are out at present, how can I get to Bathurst / Penrith and Sydney the easieset?

Tags: australia, event-based-effects, new-south-wales

Currently [there is a big outage on the line](https://www.transport.nsw.gov.au/news-and-events/media-releases/blue-mountains-line-disruption-following-freight-train-derailment).

I'll be in Katoomba for Christmas.

Boxing Day, I'd like to get to either Bathurst or Penrith or Sydney for the Boxing Day sales.

Are the only options taking a rail replacement bus? Or is there a reasonably priced alternative?

Comment: Ouch! 10 km of track damaged, that's quite a lot. "_more than 15,000 sleepers will need to be replaced, 120 broken rails fixed, and electrical work undertaken to restore signalling along the entire section of damaged track_". That'll take a while...

Answer (score 9):

According to [Transport NSW](https://transportnsw.info/news/2022/blue-mountains-line-disruption-following-freight-train-derailment), the line is disrupted between Katoomba and Springwood, so if you want to go to Bathurst, you should be able to board at Katoomba and take a train more-or-less as usual. If you wish to go towards Sydney, you will indeed have to board the rail replacement bus in order to meet the train at Springwood.

Needless to say, the situation is quite dynamic and you should recheck [the journey planner](https://transportnsw.info/trip) as close to your expected departure as possible in case of any late changes.